# Adding CSS when you access a URL with a specific ID in it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a page with multiple headers, which all have there own ID. The idea is when you click on a specific link, it takes you to the page with the headers and will scroll down to the appropriate header. However on some of the pages, there isn't enough content for the page to scroll down and for the header to site at the top of the page. So I want to highlight the header that the content references, so it's clear which content the link represents.

So the link would be something like

```
http://website.com/test#headerOne

http://website.com/test#headerTwo
```

Then once you've accessed the URL http://website.com/test#headerOne it would drop you down to  on the page. But the page isn't long enough for the header to sit at the top of the page. So i want to be able to add a background colour to the header.

Updated HTML:

```
<h3> Header One </h3>
<a name="headerOne"></a>

<p>Content here</p>
```

I'm persuming some Jquery would need doing but not sure where to start with it. I was thinking of detecting the URL and then doing an if else statement, but this seems like a long winded approach.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: dynamically add css via jquery http://api.jquery.com/css/ oru use add class/remove class methods http://api.jquery.com/addClass/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `:target`:

```
/* I'm obviously assuming you're using h2 elements for headers,
   but adjust to taste */
h2:target {
    background-color: #ffa;
}
```

Or, if you need to support older browsers without `:target` support:

```
var el = document.getElementById(document.location.hash);
el.style.backgroundColor = '#ffa';
```

And, with a function:

```
function hashChanged(){
    var el = document.getElementById(document.location.hash);
    el.style.backgroundColor = '#ffa';
}

document.addEventListener('hashChange', hashChanged, false);
```

Or, to use classes (as suggested by [@Fabrizio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17106932/adding-css-when-you-access-a-url-with-a-specific-id-in-it/17106983#comment24749132_17106983), which I should have thought of myself):

```
function hashChanged(){
    var el = document.getElementById(document.location.hash),
        highlight = 'headerHighlight';
    document.querySelector('.' + highlight).classList.remove(highlight)
    el.classList.add(highlight);
}

document.addEventListener('hashChange', hashChanged, false);
```

And use CSS to define the particulars of the class:

```
.headerHighlight {
    background-color: #ffa;
}
```

Comment: +1 but instead of changing the `style.backgroundColor` via javascript it's better to add a class with predefined style.

Comment: Thank you! Apologies i didn't realise it's actually an a tag that's holding the #ID. So it's like so <h3>header one</h3><a name="headerOne">

Comment: Named-anchors should be removed, as they're [obsolete](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/a.html), [as of HTML5](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a); use an `id` on the element you want to show instead.

Answer (score 5):

> So I want to highlight the header...

Use `:target` pseudoclass : http://css-tricks.com/on-target/

Just an example (with a smooth animation):

```
h2 {
   background: none;
   transition: background 3s linear 0; 
}

h2:target {
   background: #000;
}
```

Comment: +1 As the answer is correct, but the other answer included a little more detail

Comment: I agree, other answer gives some hints for older browser.